# What's the best and safe way to restart MySQL remotely

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I have 1 server (server A) that runs a bunch on unmaintained script and I need to monitor MySQL and restart it when it gets stuck sometimes with complex queries.

What I'm planing to do is to create a PHP script and run it with cron every minute in another server (Monitor) that will be the monitor.

Server A has a php script that queries MySQL and it it takes more than 3 seconds to respond, it will return an error code.

So, server B has a script that runs with cron every minute and make a request with curl to the script in server A. If it gets the error code, it will make a request to a second script on server A that inserts a value in the first line of a txt file.

If server A doesn't respond to requests from server B, it will send an email alert to the admin.

Server A has a shell script that runs with cron every 30 seconds. Reads the txt file, and if the value is there, it restarts mysql and erases the value from the txt file.

So all process goes back to normal.

Is the a safe way, better than give sudo permitions to apache and restart MySQL through shell_exec()?

So far I have accomplished all other tasks except the shell script.

Ho do I read the 1st line of a test file in a Shell script and if it has a value, erase it? And how to restart Mysql?

Comment: SideNote: You can't run cron job every 30 sec, anything less than 1 minute is not possible, as cron demon scans for jobs every 1 minute. Even setting Job to everyone minute is not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for Nagios and Eventhandlers, see http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/eventhandlers.html
You can check for some statements or the connection itself and if it fails Nagios (NRPE in this case, I think) can automatically execute a "/etc/init.d/mysql restart" or whatever you want.

//Edit: You can tell Nagios to do your query every X seconds